# RPA- UiPath, Regarding Special Keystrokes

Tags: rpa, uipath

How to send the keystrokes such as Alt +E+A+B, tried to send the keys using type into while working with, Alt the button is not getting released after the process is closed. Also tried to send Alt+E but not able to send the rest of the Key strokes, is there any way to send all the key strokes at a time.

Any suggestion will helpful.

Comment: I think this link may be useful: [how-to-insert-combination-keys](https://forum.uipath.com/t/how-to-insert-combination-keys-ex-shift-f3/851)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Send Hotkey activity to send hotkeys to an application:

[image: Send hotkey]

Answer (score 10):

You have a few options depending on how you want to pass along the special keys. As referenced by @Sebax in the Question's comments and [@Mads T's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53261486/302919) I thought it would be good to go into more details.

When using Type Into activity, you have three methods depending on your needs

1. **Default** Slowest of the three methods, using the hardware driver. It does NOT automatically erase pre-existing text nor does it work in the background, but supports special key strings (e.g. `[k(enter)]`)
2. **SendWindowMessages** It does *NOT* automatically erase pre-existing text but does work in the background while supporting special key strings (e.g. `[k(enter)]`)
3. **SimulateType** is the fastest of the three methods. It automatically erases pre-existing text and works in the background but does not support special key strings (e.g. `[k(enter)]`), in this case, you'll want to pair it with the [`Send Hotkey`](https://activities.uipath.com/docs/send-hotkey) activity.

**Special Key Strings**

> I've seen mention of `k`, `d`, and `u` in the UiPath Forums here and there, but have not seen official documentation that explains the modifiers or lists out the available special characters asides from looking at the [`Send Hotkey`](https://activities.uipath.com/docs/send-hotkey) dropdown list.

- **k**: Synthesize a key down (*press*) followed by a key up (*release*) for the specified key.
- **d**: Synthesize a key down (*press and hold*) event for the specified key.
- **u**: Synthesize a key up (*release*) event for the specified key.

**Special Key examples**

1. `"Hello[k(enter)"` will type out "`Hello`" followed by a carriage return.
2. `"[d(alt)]efun[u(alt)]Hello[k(enter)k(esc)]"` would

   1. Press down and hold the `Alt` key
   2. Press the keys `e`, `f`, `u`, and `n`
   3. Release the `Alt` Key
   4. Type the characters `Hello`
   5. Press the `Enter` key
   6. Press the `Esc` key

**Send Hotkey**
The send hotkey is pretty straightforward. Indicate the key(s) you want to send and if needed check the key modifiers (`Alt`, `Ctrl`, `Shift`, `Win`). If the key you are sending is a special key (e.g. `Enter`), then you'll also want to enable the `SpecialKey` property of the activity.

Send Hotkey can use the `Default` or `SendWindowMessages` inputs.

[image: Send Hotkey]

**References:**

- UiPath: [Example of using input methods](https://studio.uipath.com/docs/example-of-using-input-methods)
- UiPath: [Input Methods](https://studio.uipath.com/docs/input-methods)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, having one more doubt in a citrix environment i need to traverse through few text fields to enter a value at a certain text field, so in this situation if my control is at the first field and i want to enter value at the Tenth field then, I am using a Type into and sending "[k(tab)][k(tab)][k(tab)][k(tab)][k(tab)][k(tab)][k(tab)][k(tab)][k(tab)][k(tab)]". Is there any solution for sending multiple Tabs. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: @KHV - Glad the answer helped you out. It would be appreciated and helpful to others if you marked the answer as accepted.

Comment: @KHV - You could do a few things such as send the keys in a loop, or use one of the string functions to build a string of tabs for you. I'd suggest opening a new question for your issue if you need ideas beyond that.

Comment: Its maybe poking out, but isn't there any security issue with that ? I mean it would be able to do simple command injection (start a cmd, delete files, etc, quite easly), and might be faulty for some string (even if it's unlikely).

Answer (score 0):

You could always do a 'Type Into' method.
Then just have something like the below:

```
"[d(ctrl)]g[u(ctrl)]" + pasteLocation + "[k(enter)]" + "[d(ctrl)]v[u(ctrl)]" +  "[d(ctrl)]s[u(ctrl)]"
```

All the above does is in Excel; goes to the Cell Variable and pastes in then Saves